# Lost Immediate window option under Debug->Windows menu item

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I re-build my laptop and installed Visual Studio Team System 2008 (Development Edition) Version 9.0.30729 SP. When I am debugging, under Debug -> Windows menu item, I don't the option "Immediate". I used to get this option before. I think I had the same version of VS installed before too but not sure why I am not getting this option anymore. I used to use this window a lot and really want to have it back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries, found what was causing this
http://www.vitalygorn.com/blog/post/2008/01/28/Missing-Immediate-Window-in-VS2008.aspx